# libtool: unrecognized option `-g'

Tags: gcc, g++, libtool

I try to install a seplib software (standford exploration project), but there's a problem that I don't know how to solve, I spend too much time trying to solve it but nothing,  a lit bit more about the issue...

> Makefile:860: warning: overriding recipe for target 'install-data-local'
>   Makefile:840: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'install-data-local'
>   /bin/bash: ../../include/fullpath: csh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
>   ../../../seplib_base/include/ratsep -dofpp -DLINUX -DSOURCE='"'/Sort3d.f90s'"' Sort3d.f90s
>   0: ../../../seplib_base/tools/spp/spp ./Sort3d.f90
>   /bin/bash: ../../include/fullpath: csh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
>   ifort -g -FR -I../../../seplib_base/lib/corelibs/sep -I../../../seplib_base/lib/corelibs/sep3d -I../../../seplib_base/lib/corelibs/superset -I../../../seplib_base/lib/class/gee -I../../../seplib_base/lib/util/sepaux -I../../../seplib_base/lib/util/math -I../../../seplib_base/lib/util/fft -I../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/velan -I../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/image -I../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/wei -I../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/filter -I../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/dip -I../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/model -I../../../seplib_base/lib/util/par -DSOURCE='"'/Sort3d.f90'"'    -c -o Sort3d.o Sort3d.f90
>   /bin/bash: ../../include/fullpath: csh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
>   /bin/bash ../../libtool --mode=link   -g -FR -I../../../seplib_base/lib/corelibs/sep -I../../../seplib_base/lib/corelibs/sep3d -I../../../seplib_base/lib/corelibs/superset -I../../../seplib_base/lib/class/gee -I../../../seplib_base/lib/util/sepaux -I../../../seplib_base/lib/util/math -I../../../seplib_base/lib/util/fft -I../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/velan -I../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/image -I../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/wei -I../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/filter -I../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/dip -I../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/model -I../../../seplib_base/lib/util/par -DSOURCE='"'/Sort3d.o'"'   -L../../../seplib_base/lib/corelibs/sep -L../../../seplib_base/lib/corelibs/sep3d -L../../../seplib_base/lib/corelibs/superset -L../../../vplot/libvplot -L../../../seplib_base/lib/graphics/glplot -L../../../seplib_base/lib/class/gee -L../../../seplib_base/lib/util/math -L../../../seplib_base/lib/util/sepaux -L../../../seplib_base/lib/util/fft -L../../../seplib_base/lib/util/par -L../../../seplib_base/lib/util/vector -L../../../seplib_base/lib/util/convert -L../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/travel -L../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/velan -L../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/filter -L../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/image -L../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/wei -L../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/dip -L../../../seplib_base/lib/util/cwp -L../../../seplib_base/lib/seis/model -o Sort3d  Sort3d.o -lsepauxf90 -lsepaux -lsepconvertf90 -lsepconvert -lsep3df90 -lsep3d -lsepf90 -lsep  -lsep2df90 -lsep3df90 -lsep3d -lsepf90 -lsep  -lsepmathf90 -Vaxlib -lm
>   libtool: unrecognized option `-g`
>   Try `libtool --help' for more information.

I tried to remove -g -FR -I and the problem passed, but other scripts need a sep library, so I can't continue with the installation

Please I need help, I spend too much time in this part and I really need this software.

Comment: I need to say that I already installed libtiff5-dev and I have ifort too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the build problem is caused by this error:

```
 /bin/bash: ../../include/fullpath: csh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Apparently, you need to install a csh implementation (such as tcsh) in order to build this software.

The missing csh interpreter resulted in a garbled command line for the libtool command, hence the error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, the problem goes on, I already have installed the newest version of tcsh and csh, and I do the configuration again, but the problem still remains.